# Сортировка списка по модулю 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, сортировка, list

Задание стоит так: есть список чисел, его нужно отсортировать по модулю 3. Как это сделать лучше всего?

Comment: лучше всего воспользоваться встроенной функцией `sorted()` ;)

Comment: можно подробнее? использовать какой-то ключ к ней?

Comment: то есть написать функцию, которая определяет числа по модулю 3, а потом ее использовать как ключ

Comment: здесь принято помогать тем, кто что-то пытается сделать сам. Приведите попытки самостоятельного решения в вопросе и вам сразу помогут ;) Также не помешает привести в воспросе небольшой пример входных и выходных данных...

Comment: `список.sort(key=lambda x: x % 3)`

Comment: Спасибо, помогло